# Convert vector UDT to double in ML

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I applied my logistic regression function and I have a "probability" column which type is VectorUDT.
I wouldlike to take the first element of it and make a new column with DoubleType in order to save it to csv.

Is there any way to do that ?